# Jailbroken iPhone stuck on boot screen

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, startup

I tried to reload Cydia, which stopped working on my jailbroken iPhone 4. I downloaded "Redsnow" and "Ipsw 4.3.2", which worked, until I went to use and downloaded an app with Cydia.

I did not realize that this jailbreak version needed to be tethered to reboot! 
So i put my iPhone back in sleep mode and boot from Redsnow only to have it get locked in the logo boot mode for 2 days now! Yesterday I panicked and downloaded the latest update from iTunes and did a factory instal with no avail - still in this boot logo loop

How can I fix this and use my phone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first put your phone into [DFU Mode](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034). Then, run Redsnow, go to "Extras" and select "Just Boot".

Answer (score 0):

My suggest would be to [restore your iPhone using iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) and re-jailbreak it using the latest [Absinthe](http://www.absinthejailbreak.net/) which supports jailbreaking the most recent iOS 5.1.1.